# Running "npm run build" before running Flask via gunicorn

Tags: node.js, vue.js, flask, heroku

I'm trying to run a somewhat custom setup, and I don't know what the modern method is.

I have a Vue.js + Flask application which runs on my development machine just fine.

`npm run build` compiles a production ready version of the app, and `vue.config.js` makes sure it outputs at `./dist/`, which my Flask server at `./server/create_app.py` serves.

I don't upload the `dist` folder to GitHub, but I want it to be built on deploy at Heroku. How do I get `npm run build` to be ran before my Flask server is ran with gunicorn (web:).

`package.json` is located at `./client/package.json` along with all client files.

./Procfile

```
web: gunicorn wsgi:app
```

Comment: [Customizing build process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process), `npm build` is something Heroku understands. You can extend it further with `heroku-prebuild`, `heroku-postbuild` and `heroku-cleanup`

Comment: Unfortunately, this only seems to work when `package.json` is in the root directory. Mine is located at `./client/package.json`, meaning it won't run automatically. I don't know if Heroku provides any way to get around this limitation, I'm not seeing anything relevant.

Comment: You can have multiple `package.json`. The root directory one you just put in for the script `cd client && <command which you would have usually run in the client folder>`